# Beamer: Add the frame number to the footer

Tags: beamer, footer, number, frame

With beamer, I would like to add the frame number to the footer.
I am using texlive 20200327.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{Beamer Example}

% https://texblog.net/latex-archive/uncat ... me-number/
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
\oldmacro\hfill%
\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{First section}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There is a problem in the output:
[image]

The frame number "1 / 2" at the bottom is not aligned to the right of the page.

How to fix that please?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:** [@samcarter](https://latex.org/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=59081) posted an excellent solution with compilable example at the forum thread below:

```
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
```

That's enough and you can remove that whole `\insertshorttitle` redefinition. I also updated the old blog post you referred to, with samcarter's fix.

So consider my `\@gobbletwo` fix below just as some way to quickly modify the existing code.

---

As I already wrote as answer to [Beamer: Add the frame number to the footer on LaTeX.org](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=34369)

The `footline` template of the `split` theme contains this code:

```
\insertshorttitle\nobreak\hfill
```

Because of the `\hfill`, there's empty space at the right. To remove that space and so getting the frame numbers right aligned, you could use the `\@gobbletwo` command that ignores the next two commands `\nobreak\hfill`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\@gobbletwo}
\makeatother
```

It's a quick hack though. See the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I redefined the footline of the template so that the frame number and total frame number move further to the right.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{Beamer Example}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \mbox{}\hfill\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle \hfill \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{First section}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]